# How to get metal live spot price

Tags: php

I am developing a jewelry website and I need to integrate live spot price with currency. Can you please let me know any free available service for this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[xml feed](http://www.xmlcharts.com/precious-metals.html)

This one is hourly updated